# У меня возникла проблема со своей веткой

Tags: git, gitlab

Я сделал новую ветку (допустим branch), от релизной ветки (release), чтобы добавить некую фичу, допустим я сделал 3 коммита, запушил и создал MergeRequest, но ещё многое надо сделать, поэтому у меня draft-версия.
Меня беспокоил определенный тест, который не проходил и мне посоветовали "подлить от веточки основной", я сделал , что то типо такого (сижу на branch, git status чистый):

1. git fetch
2. git merge origin/release
   ...
   Ко мне залилось много изменений, испугался... я их откатил в VSC стрелочкой назад(или "-" минус) в SourceControl.
   git status - всё чисто.
   Далее решил поменять код немного и пушнуть.
   Так вот запушилось всё то, что я якобы откатил.

Как убрать все изменения в branch и в origin/branch??

Comment: `VSC стрелочкой назад(или "-" минус)` - не понятно что там реально произошло. Либо git revert, либо git checkout ... Покажите выхлоп git reflog - там будет ясно. Ну и git log из ветки branch

Comment: Сори, что не ответил раньше...Проблему помог решить ТимЛид, мне особо не объяснил..